# Recebendo um array como parâmetro em uma função PHP

Tags: php, array, funções

Bem, o assunto pode ser antigo mas surgiu essa dúvida e não paciência em reescrever o código...

O seguinte código, não está gerando resultado.

Há uma função que basicamente está assim:

```
function Preco(&$p)
{
$soma=array();

    foreach ($p as $pcos):
        foreach($faixaEtaria as $qtde):

            $soma=$pcos*$qtde;

        endforeach;
    endforeach;

$resultado=array_sum($soma);

return $resultado;
}
```

Ela está sendo chamada desta forma:

```
$Preco1=Preco($matrizPrecos);
```

A função recebe um 'array' contendo os preços...

Dentro da função crio outra array, cujos elementos recebem o produto entre aquele array de preços e um array de 'quantidades', cada.

Após, só peço a soma dos elementos desse array "da casa".

Retorno o resultado.

Desde já agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Ok. Qual é o problema ?

Comment: Não funciona...

Comment: Acredito que esteja faltando informações. Você faz um foreach em **$faixaEtaria** de onde vem isso ? E porque você tem um *&* como parâmetro da função ?

Comment: $faixaEtaria é outro array, nunca está zerado.  O "&" seria para referenciar ao endereço, já que colocando de forma normal não estava funcionando (como continua não funcionando). Exceto "$soma[]", todos os arrays existem e possuem conteúdo no código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populei os `arrays` com valores fictícios para averiguar se tinha algum erro. E encontrei alguns.
Segue o código corrigido que retorna os valores:

```
        function Preco($p){
            //$faixaEtaria = array(10, 20);
            $soma = array();

            foreach ($p as $pcos):
                foreach($faixaEtaria as $qtde):

                    $soma[] = $pcos * $qtde;

                endforeach;
            endforeach;

            $resultado = array_sum($soma);
            return $resultado;
        } 

        //$matrizPrecos = array(5, 10, 15, 5);
        $Preco1 = Preco($matrizPrecos);

        echo $Preco1;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: putz! Valeu! vou testar aqui! Falta de atenção no $soma!

Comment: Espero ter ajudado ; )

Comment: Brother, consegui. O problema é em $faixaEtaria. Dentro da função após o $soma=array(); eu coloco:

global $faixaEtaria;

Assim eu a capto "lá fora".

Obrigado ae!

Comment: Boa. Fico feliz em ter contribuído.

Answer (score 0):

Após a ajuda do Ricardo Mota, só precisou adicionar o "global".. o código retorna resultado agora:

```
 function Preco($p)
{
$soma=array();

global $faixaEtaria;

    foreach ($p as $pcos):
        foreach($faixaEtaria as $qtde):

            $soma[]=$pcos*$qtde;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

$resultado=array_sum($soma);

return $resultado;
}
```